# I want to disable or hidden default keys on my Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

When I develop a Windows Phone application, how can I disable or hidden numbers on number pad using XAML code?

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, i.e., why you want to do this?  Frequently questions like this can be improved by taking a step back and saying "how can I accomplish goal Y", rather than "how can I do X to accomplish Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can customize the Windows Phone keyboard, so the simple answer is that you cannot do this.

But as usual there is a possible workaround. :-) You could design your own UI that mimics a keyboard. This would allow you to completely control how the keyboard works and what keys kan be pressed.

There might be other solutions as well, but you need to better describe your case before we can look into that.